# How to create a vba which selects a random amount of character within a given limit?

Tags: vba

This is the simplest way to select the specific number of character

`Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend`

I'm having a problem with incorporating the random function.

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub extendSelRndCharacters()
   Dim iMin As Long, iMax As Long, nrCount As Long
   iMax = 5: iMin = 1 'limits for number of characters to be operated
   Randomize
   nrCount = Int((iMax - iMin + 1) * Rnd + iMin)
   Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=nrCount, Extend:=wdExtend
End Sub
```

Comment: @Luke Brakes Didn't the above code solve your problem? Did you find some time to test it?

Comment: Yes, it worked. thank you! The difference between the randomized output is small but it gets the job done.